# c# classes when converting to XML not showing elements

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to create an XMl request using c# classes.

Intended output is

```
<UserRequest>
  <action>manage</action>
  <create>
    <name>Companies</name>
    <item>
    <symbol>GOOG</symbol>
    <item />
  </create>
 </UserRequest>
```

When I create classes like below using XMl attributes

```
[XmlRoot("WorkflowRequest")]
    public class UserRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public string action { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("create")]
        public Create create { get; set; }
    }


    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class Create
    {       
        public string name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("item")]
        public Item item { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
    public class Item
    {
        public string symbolType;       
        public string symbol;
        public string qty;
        public string purchasePrice;
        public string purchaseCost;
        public string purchaseDate;
        public string putOrCall;
        public string strikePrice;
        public string expirationDate;
    }
```

and

```
Item symbolInfo = new Item();
symbolInfo.symbol = "GOOG";

Create ct = new Create()
{
     name = "Companies",
     item = symbolInfo
};
UserRequest userRequest = new UserRequest()
{
     action = "manage",
     create = ct
 };
```

I get a weird request with item tag as  instead of GOOG.. Can someone please guide where I did wrong
This is what i got..

```
<UserRequest>
  <action>manage</action>
  <create>
    <name>Companies</name>
    <item />
  </create>
 </UserRequest>
```

Comment: Your intended and actual outputs are identical. How did you try to serialize those objects and what did you actually get? Just because you used the `XmlRoot` attribute doesn't say whether you used XmlSerializer, XDocument or DataContractSerializer

Comment: um... where is that different from the intended output?

Comment: @dlatikay I am completely lost as well.

Comment: Also, when I compare your models, created instances and the request, the resulting request looks exactly as I would expect.

Comment: My bad. I changed it.. item is showing as an empty element..

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - please check now

Comment: @Ram your `Item` class has no properties, only fields. Serializers work with properties

Comment: thats it, I know now how it works.. Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Item
{    
    [XmlElement("symbol")]
    public string symbol;

    //other properties
}
```